# Activity Releasing Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a custom camera running in a Fragment.
When the OnPictureTaken function is called the Activity releases the Fragment hence getActivity is returning NULL and "Fragment Not Attached To Activity".

As the picture is successfully taken.
onPictureTaken is called.
There I want to start an Activity.

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mOrientationListener = new CameraOrientationListener(context);
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mOrientationListener = new CameraOrientationListener(activity);
        activity2 = activity;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Restore your state here because a double rotation with this fragment
        // in the backstack will cause improper state restoration
        // onCreate() -> onSavedInstanceState() instead of going through onCreateView()
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mCameraID = getBackCameraID();
            mFlashMode = CameraSettingPreferences.getCameraFlashMode(getActivity());
            mImageParameters = new ImageParameters();

        } else {
            mCameraID = savedInstanceState.getInt(CAMERA_ID_KEY);
            mFlashMode = savedInstanceState.getString(CAMERA_FLASH_KEY);
            mImageParameters = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(IMAGE_INFO);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.squarecamera__fragment_camera_demo, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mOrientationListener.enable();

        mPreviewView = (SquareCameraPreview) view.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview_view);
        mPreviewView.getHolder().addCallback(CameraFragment.this);

        final View topCoverView = view.findViewById(R.id.cover_top_view);
        final View btnCoverView = view.findViewById(R.id.cover_bottom_view);

        mImageParameters.mIsPortrait =
                getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            ViewTreeObserver observer = mPreviewView.getViewTreeObserver();
            observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    mImageParameters.mPreviewWidth = mPreviewView.getWidth();
                    mImageParameters.mPreviewHeight = mPreviewView.getHeight();

                    mImageParameters.mCoverWidth = mImageParameters.mCoverHeight
                            = mImageParameters.calculateCoverWidthHeight();

//                    Log.d(TAG, "parameters: " + mImageParameters.getStringValues());
//                    Log.d(TAG, "cover height " + topCoverView.getHeight());
                    resizeTopAndBtmCover(topCoverView, btnCoverView);

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        mPreviewView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    } else {
                        mPreviewView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            if (mImageParameters.isPortrait()) {
                topCoverView.getLayoutParams().height = mImageParameters.mCoverHeight;
                btnCoverView.getLayoutParams().height = mImageParameters.mCoverHeight;
            } else {
                topCoverView.getLayoutParams().width = mImageParameters.mCoverWidth;
                btnCoverView.getLayoutParams().width = mImageParameters.mCoverWidth;
            }
        }

        final ImageView swapCameraBtn = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.change_camera);
        swapCameraBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mCameraID == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                    mCameraID = getBackCameraID();
                } else {
                    mCameraID = getFrontCameraID();
                }
                restartPreview();
            }
        });

        final View changeCameraFlashModeBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.flash);
        changeCameraFlashModeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mFlashMode.equalsIgnoreCase(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO)) {
                    mFlashMode = Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON;
                } else if (mFlashMode.equalsIgnoreCase(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON)) {
                    mFlashMode = Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF;
                } else if (mFlashMode.equalsIgnoreCase(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF)) {
                    mFlashMode = Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO;
                }

                setupFlashMode();
                setupCamera();
            }
        });

        final ImageView takePhotoBtn = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.capture_image_button);
        takePhotoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takePicture();
            }
        });
    }
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return;

        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                break;

            default:
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }


    //This is the Function Where it lands after the Picture is taken
    /**
     * A picture has been taken
     * @param data
     * @param camera
     */
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
          rotation = getPhotoRotation();
        DisplayPicFragment.newInstance(data, rotation,mImageParameters.createCopy());
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayPicActivity.class));
//        if(isAdded()){
//            startActivity(new Intent(activity2, DisplayPicActivity.class));
//        }

        setSafeToTakePhoto(true);
    }
```

Comment: Your talking about code we don't have... please provide some code so we can understand the structure of your fragment and the life-cycle of the callbacks you are referring to.

Comment: Edited. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

From your `DisplayPicActivity` I understand that you want to display the picture.

There is a method for that - [`setPreviewDisplay (SurfaceHolder holder)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewDisplay(android.view.SurfaceHolder)).

Comment: Yes jamal. Thank you, Ill see to it.