# Switch activity onPictureTaken

Tags: android, camera, fragment

The activity is not starting, its returning null, if explicitly defining it, the error is "Fragment is not attached to the activity". Well, if the fragment is not attached to the activity then how is the fragment being hosted and ALIVE?

Comment: Whats the point in down voting, I mean Im having an issue I asked a question, tell is it a grave mistake I have done?

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make your question clear by adding related part of code, crash logs in post. instead of just saving `The activity is not starting, its returning null`

Comment: I did posted my same problem thrice, no one bats an eye :/

Comment: I did include the code, for you my friend Im posting it again, do take a look, and help me out first then you can down vote it accordingly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activity Releasing Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980307/activity-releasing-fragment)

Comment: If you are deliberately re-posting your previous questions on Stack Overflow, then that in itself is grounds for downvoting. Please don't do this! If you find that a question is not getting enough answers, keep editing it with whatever new things you are trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue, by implementing the Picture.CallBack interface in my FragmentActivity.